# Union of two tables in MATLAB, only taking rows in one table

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have two MATLAB tables:

```
>> x = table({'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'}', (1:4)', 'VariableNames', {'theKey' 'theValue'})
x = 
    theKey    theValue
    ______    ________
    'a'       1       
    'b'       2       
    'c'       3       
    'd'       4       
>> y = table({'b' 'c'}', [998 999]', 'VariableNames', {'theKey' 'theValue'})
y = 
    theKey    theValue
    ______    ________
    'b'       998      
    'c'       999
```

Is there a procedure (some type/combination of union/join/outerjoin maybe) which returns me the union of the two tables, but only keeps the rows from the 2nd table if there is duplication according to a key I choose (`theKey`)? For example, I'm looking to have this output:

```
    theKey    theValue
    ______    ________
    'a'       1       
    'b'       998       
    'c'       999       
    'd'       4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking at unioning using [`outerjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html) in matlab. I don't think there's a way just to do this with joins, but you may have to play some games with indexing.

```
>> b=outerjoin(x,y,'Type','left','MergeKeys',true,'LeftKeys',{'theKey'},'RightKeys',{'theKey'})

ans = 

    theKey    theValue_x    theValue_y
    ______    __________    __________

    'a'       1             NaN       
    'b'       2             998       
    'c'       3             999       
    'd'       4             NaN       

>> b.(2)(~isnan(b.(3)))=b.(3)(~isnan(b.(3)))

    theKey    theValue_x    theValue_y
    ______    __________    __________

    'a'       1             NaN       
    'b'       998           998       
    'c'       999           999       
    'd'       4             NaN   

>> b.(3)=[]

    theKey    theValue_x
    ______    __________

    'a'         1       
    'b'       998       
    'c'       999       
    'd'         4
```

Comment: Your previous output does not match what MATLAB would produce when you run those commands, so I shuffled your post around to match what it's supposed to give.

Comment: Thanks, I'm of the belief that there is no 1-liner which does what I want. I also have a 3-liner:
[~, i] = ismember(x.theKey, y.theKey);
output = x;
output(i > 0, :) = y(i(i > 0), :);
Thanks anyway!